# How to find string in a character in R

Tags: r, string

I know this is a very naive question, but I tried a lot but didn't find a way to count the number of occurrences of a specified substring within a character string in R.

For example:

```
str <- "Hello this is devavrata! here, say again hello"
```

Now I want to find the number of occurrences of `hello`, ignoring case. In this example, the answer should come out to be 2.
**EDIT:** I am wondering that it when I will find `ello th` then `str_count` will give occurrence `1` but I want the exact word surrounded by spaces occurrence means in this case it should give `zero`.
 For example if I want to find `very good` in a particular **string** like:-

`It is very good to speak like thevery good`

And occurence should be `1` here not `2`. I hope you understand.

Comment: Could you show it in a `string` and your expected result.

Comment: I did some updates, check if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also try:

```
 library(stringi)
  stri_count(str, regex="(?i)hello")
  #[1] 2


  str1 <- "It is very good to speak like thevery good"
  stri_count(str1, regex="\\b(?i)very good\\b")
 #[1] 1
```

Comment: I am wondering that it when I will find `ello th` then `str_count` will give occurrence `1` but I want the exact word surrounded by spaces occurrence means in this case it should give `zero`.

Comment: Thanx it works great!! do `stringi` package needs load `lattice` package

Comment: @Devavrata I don't know whether it requires lattice as dependency, but one thing is that it is very fast for these operations.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest and most straightforward way would be to use `str_count` from  `stringr`

```
str <- "Hello this is devavrata! here, say again hello"
library(stringr)
str_count(str, ignore.case("hello"))
# [1] 2
```

Two base R methods are

```
length(grep("hello", strsplit(str, " ")[[1]], ignore.case = TRUE))
# [1] 2
```

and

```
sum(gregexpr("hello", str, ignore.case = TRUE)[[1]] > 0)
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks... I have Tried the grep but it will go wrong when I have to find string like `"very good"` and that is the main problem, I was facing

Comment: @Devavrata - string matching is very specific, so it would need to be adjusted for different matching criteria.

Comment: Exactly but in my scheme it was main problem, But this is solved by `str_count`.I don't want to divide my string in vector.

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party but I think the `termco` function from the `qdap` package does exactly what you want.  You use leading and/or trailing spaces to control word boundaries as seen in the example below:

```
x <- c("Hello this is devavrata! here, say again hello",
    "It is very good to speak like thevery good")

library(qdap)
(out <- termco(x, id(x), list("hello", "very good", " very good ")))

##   x word.count     hello very good very good
## 1 1          8 2(25.00%)         0         0
## 2 2          9         0 2(22.22%) 1(11.11%)

## To get a data frame of pure counts:
out %>% counts()

##   x word.count hello very good very good
## 1 1          8     2         0         0
## 2 2          9     0         2         1
```